# How to configure Azure AAD in API Management and call API Management endpoints from web/console app in .NET

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I have gone through few articles like below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

but It didnt worked.

I'm getting error as `AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '24gktm5-5khpnj3h9nphkmm=h-hh2h58h9'`.

I have followed everything as mentioned but not getting where I did wrong.

Also can someone share code to call APIM endpoints from console app.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URIs for your AD app (Application ID : 24gktm5-5khpnj3h9nphkmm=h-hh2h58h9) needs to include the URI from the OAuth configuration under APIM.

From the OAuth settings of APIM, under where you enter the client secret you should see "This is what the redirect_uri for authorization code grant type looks like", copy this URL into the redirect URIs for your AD app registration.

Comment: Thanks @MynciMan for your reply. I want to call API management endpoints through web app or console app or webapi using Azure AAD token. Can you guide me on this. I have been struggling for this from long time.

Comment: I found the following guide helpful in setting up OAUTH support for the developer console [link](https://winterdom.com/2017/11/09/oauth2-apimanagement). It's worth noting that only the legacy developer portal currently supports this. If you're calling the endpoint from a webapp you can take advantage of managed service identity. If you're calling from a console app you'll need a client id and secret, the appauthentication package helps with this [link](https://blog.novanet.no/managed-identity-and-microsoft-azure-services-appauthentication/)